# How do I use the Composite of Continuous Functions theorem to show that a function is continuous?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, function-and-relation-composition

$$f(x)= \sqrt \frac{x}{x+1}$$
I know that I have to split it into two separate functions:
$$ g(x)= \sqrt x$$
$$h(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$$
I'm just not sure what to do next, and I can't seem to find anything that explains it well enough (or simply enough, I guess). Am I just an idiot? Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest you use the definition of continuity.

In case you were just told "you can't pick up your pencil", try the definition that $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$.

Comment: continuous on what domain?

Comment: $g$ and $h$ are continuous and $f(x) = g(h(x)$ (which you figured out). Then the theorem you quote says $f$ is continuous where it's defined- nothing more is required, unless you are supposed to find the domain of $f$ too. Can you figure out what values of $x$ will cause trouble?

Comment: If you've already shown that $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous then you're done the first step. Otherwise, prove it, and then also prove that $h$ is continuous. This can be done by recalling the theorem that says that the quotient of two continuous functions is continuous whenever the denominator is nonzero (notice that $g$ is just the quotient of $x$ and $x+1$, polynomials).

Comment: @EthanBolker Oh, that makes sense. Thank you!